# Cross-sectional study design with no control group compares 2 treatment arms

Tags: experiment-design, causality, cross-section

There is a trend among medical research that assesses cross sectional (singular point in time) treatment comparisons between 2 treated groups in retrospective data. In other words the  a person who took drug A and drug B, but no placebo group is included.

What is the literature like on these sort of designs and the obvious drawbacks on lacking a control group? I've seen methods like synthetic controls and front-door estimators that can provide useful estimation of certain treatment effects, under strong assumptions, but all of these methods are on data with multiple time points. Is there any method that works under a singular time point?

Comment: In what sense is there a single time point? Do they mean the treatment and outcome were measured at the same time point but refer to events at different time points (e.g., $X$=how many cigarettes did you smoke last month; $Y$=what is your blood pressure today) or the treatment and outcome actually occurred simultaneously ($X$=are you smoking; $Y$=what is your blood pressure)? The causal structure of the system under investigation is distinct from the causal structure of the measurement tool.

Comment: Comparing two drugs without a placebo is just a comparative effectiveness design. Not having a control group doesn't affect the strength of the design, just the interpretation of the effect.

Comment: There would be little-to-no safety aspect gleaned from such a study. In my opinion, this kind of design should be illegal.

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes, I see many competing views on this, but there is not much clear empirical evidence on what a lack of control means for the overall result and interpreting an effect. could you explain more with citations?

Comment: @Noah patients received either treatment a or treatment b and then outcome is assessed at 30 days

Comment: Then in what sense is this a cross-sectional study? It seems like you have two time points: one where the patients received the treatment and one where the outcome is assessed 30 days later. Also, not sure if Adrian is referring to the lack of placebo being problematic, but if you are studying two well-established safe drugs, this design can help you compare them.